# WCF call to a server in another transaction

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a webservice appliation (in server1) and a method (processingComplete.svc) which is being called by a Windows service in another server (server2). This service would basically send a delivery id to the webservice for processing, but meantime this delivery id is being locked in the server database (server2) by the windows service.

I have to call a webservice in server2 called deliveryRetrieved.svc, letting them know that i have got the delivery id. This has to be done through my webservice method (processingComplete). But when i directly call them, it throws an exception saying the delivery id is locked. Since the first call made by the windows service (from server2) has not returned. This would be the same transaction for them. So i have end that transaction by returning from processingComplete and them trigger another call to deliveryRetrieved.svc.

Is this possible? Like it should be another transaction, so that they unlock the delivery id from their end (server2). Below is the set of code.

```
// Below is the webservice method in server1
public void processingComplete(DeliveryID deliveryid)
{
  // processing the deliveryid
 // Cant call deliveryRetrieved.svc method here as this 
 // processingComplete response has not returned back to server 2 yet
 // Need a trigger to call deliveryRetrieved once this method has completed the execution

}
```

Any leads?

Comment: Just call it at the end? There is probably a less awful way to do this entire thing though.

Comment: I can't do that. As i have not returned from the windows service call made to processingComplete. If i do that call the deliveryid is locked from his end. It will be unlocked only if the windows service gets a response from processingComplete. Can there be a trigger or something or can a callback work?

Comment: Seems like the process that takes the lock should release the lock.

Comment: Yeah can a callback work in such a case?

Comment: Maybe consider [optimistic concurrency/locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control) instead? IOW, do you really _need_ to hold locked the "deliver ID" for the complete duration?

Comment: Why did you lock it in the first place? Is that on purpose or did you just forget to commit or close your cursor?

Comment: No the locking happens in the server2 side. I have to acknowledge that i have got the id. So i cant use some kind of a call back or something else? So that processComplete is returned then  a call to deliveryRetrieved svc is made\